# List Box Duplicates

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, textbox, listbox

I'm having trouble with list boxes.
If I had a text box and an add button which places the data into the list box.
Accidentally entered the same name twice.
How do i prevent the duplicates in my list box?
Do i enter the code into the button section or under the list box?

Comment: Can you post some code? What have you already tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply check if it already exists before you add it, e.g. with Linq:

```
bool contains = lbName.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
    .Any(li => li.Text.Equals(txtName.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
if(!contains)
{
    lbName.Items.Add(new ListItem(txtName.Text));
}
```

Assuming that you want to compare case-insensitively.

**Edit** Since you actually want to add full file-paths to the `ListBox` but you want to prevent that a second file with the same file-name gets added, you can use the [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class:

```
string fullFilePath = .... 
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fullFilePath);
bool contains = lbName.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
    .Any(li => Path.GetFileName(li.Text).Equals(fileName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
if (!contains)
{
    lbName.Items.Add(new ListItem(fullFilePath));
}
```

Comment: What happens if this text box turns out to be a directory for a file browser, which adds files names to the list box but if it is pressed again the files names are re-added?

Comment: @KevinChun: I'm afraid that i cannot follow. The code works with any  strings, the source does not matter. Or do you want to add the **full path** to the file but want to prevent that a second file with the same **file-name** gets added?

Answer (score 1):

In your button click you can have something like this:

```
  if (this.listBox.Items.Contains(this.txtCustomerName.Text) == false)
  {
     this.listBox.Items.Add(this.txtCustomerName.Text);
  }
```

Or, if you're using ListItems:

```
ListItem item = new ListItem(this.txtCustomerName.Text);

if (listBox.Items.Contains(item) == false)
{
   listBox.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: what is suppose to replace txtCustomerName??

Answer (score 0):

Add the code in the button, you could even add the code to your textBox's event checking live that the text entered is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach (ListItem item in yourListITem.Items)
{
    if (item.Text == yourNewListITemText.SelectedItem.Text)
    {
        empAdd = 0;
    }
}
if(empAdd==0)
{
//Item Exist....
}
else
{
//New Add
 yourListBox.Items.Add(new ListItem(yourlistbox.SelectedItem.ToString(), yourlistbox.SelectedValue.ToString()));
}
```